# Unable to execute Powershell script via Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins, automation

I wrote this powershell script to impersonate another user with DB access, execute a select query against, export the results into a CSV and also purges historic results from a specified folder. It works great when run manually. But I want to set it up as a Jenkins job so I can grant relevant teams with access to run ad hoc. But Since Jenkins suppresses popup console window for PS process, the job fails. It throws below error in system event log:

> Application popup: powershell.exe - Application Error : The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application.

Below is the powershell script:

```
$uid='dummy\user'
$pass='password' | ConvertTo-SecureString -Force -AsPlainText
$creds=New-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($uid, $pass)
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
$query = "
USE [ReportServer]
 SELECT
 iname,
 path,
 domain,
 sid,
 [Parameters],
 note1,
 start,
 end,
 count,
 [RowCount],
 AdditionalInfo
 FROM log
 where start <  GetDate() and end  > dateadd(minute, -180, GetDate())
 ORDER BY start"
function purger (){
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp\NAS\" -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { (!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit ) -and $_.Name -Match '.csv' } | Remove-Item -Force
}
$database = "dummyDB"
$SQLInstance = "machine\database"
$connectionString ="server=$SQLInstance;trusted_connection=true;"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open() 
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query
$result = $command.ExecuteReader()
$table = new-object “System.Data.DataTable”
purger
$table.Load($result)
$table | Export-Csv -path "C:\temp\NAS-$(get-date -format yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm).csv"
Write-Host "done"
$connection.Close()
} -Credential $creds
Wait-Job $job
Receive-Job $job
```

Jenkins fails with the following output:

> Started by timer [workspace] $ powershell.exe "&
>   'C:\Users\dummyuser\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson3554646184930.ps1'"
>   Receive-Job : [localhost] The background process reported an error
>   with the fol lowing message: . At C:\temp\launcher.ps1:51 char:12
>   + Receive-Job <<<<  $execute
>       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Receive-Job], PSRemotingTranspor     tException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionStateBroken Finished: SUCCESS

Any help on this would be awesome. Thanks heaps in advance for your time.

Comment: How do you setup the build step in Jenkins? I just tried your script - works fine for me when executed as a Windows batch command ("powershell -File Script.ps1") or via Jenkins Powershell plugin.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderDrogin - That's weird because I tried both approaches you mentioned and I get 'PSSessionStateBroken' and "Application popup:" error every time. I have Powershell 2.0 installed. Do you think a firewall could be in play here? If it works for you, then I haven't a foggiest what could be wrong with my set up. I was hoping it's a script issue. :(

Comment: I tried Windows batch command as well as PS plugin but with no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am having this exact problem with PowerShell in Jenkins. When I call `Start-Process` it works but if I use the `Credential $credential` argument on `Start-Process` it fails silently and the `0xc0000142` error code appears in Event Viewer. Was there any resolution?